# Can`t see the file history in Gitlens (on a specific project)

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, git-log, git-history, gitlens

I have a problem with Gitlens extension. Firstly, Gitlens or Git History extension is working fine on any other project except the this Laravel project. My problem is, can`t see the file history or line history in this project.

On the other hand, there is no problem in the git log (Git History Extension) as seen in screenshot;

[image]

But I can't compare any files with their any version (every commit seems like in the ss). I have no idea what the problem is about.

[image]

Lastly, I don't think the problem is about extension settings because other projects do not have this problem. Is there a any chance to fix this issue without resetting git history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering after 3 months, maybe it works for someone. As I mentioned in the title, surely there is no problem about extension settings for this specific project. The problem is just about git files. Maybe, I damaged some git files while moving the project on my desktop :)

So, there is no chance to fix this issue without resetting git history or starting fresh with git, if you`re having the same problem.

> Do not play with git files, it`s no joke!

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar issue. My problem is in using symbolic links for folders.

I have this folder symlink for my repos.

```
C:\>dir
 Directory of C:\

27.09.2018  21:07    <JUNCTION>     repos [C:\Users\Qwerty\repos]
```

(GitLens v11)
The top editor is opened via `C:\repos`
The bottom editor via `C:\Users\Qwerty\repos`

[image]

You can see that some git features still work (yellow), but others don't.
However, this is very strange, because in my other repos, I have never observed such issues.

Also notice below that it is still possible to invoke the same action via a git lens popup and then it is possible to use the Prev Next Revision buttons.

[image]

Anyway, after more testing, I actually observe the same thing in my other repos. I assume that something must have changed between versions as I only observe these issues for last maybe 2-3 months. I even submitted a ticket that GitLens stopped working in v12.0.0 and later versions https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/1979
The buttons completely disappeared and even the commit information

v11
[image]
v12
[image]

And Now actually, after having reopened my repo via original path and after updating GitLens back to v12.0.6 I see that it is working properly!

Bottom editor is opened via `C:\repos` symlink.
[image]